# JavaScript array manipulation to delete odd array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help; I have an array like this:

```
myarray = ["nonsense","goodpart","nonsense2","goodpar2t","nonsense3","goodpart3",]
```

I need to delete all "nonsense" part from array.

Nonsense always have an even index.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd suggest, on the basis that 'nonsense' words are always (as stated in the question) the 'even' elements:

```js
var myarray = ["nonsense", "goodpart", "nonsense2", "goodpar2t", "nonsense3", "goodpart3"],
  filtered = myarray.filter(function(el, index) {
    // normally even numbers have the feature that number % 2 === 0;
    // JavaScript is, however, zero-based, so want those elements with a modulo of 1:
    return index % 2 === 1;
  });

console.log(filtered); // ["goodpart", "goodpar2t", "goodpart3"]
```

If, however, you wanted to filter by the array-elements themselves, to remove all words that contain the word 'nonsense':

```js
var myarray = ["nonsense", "goodpart", "nonsense2", "goodpar2t", "nonsense3", "goodpart3"],
  filtered = myarray.filter(function(el) {
    // an indexOf() equal to -1 means the passed-in string was not found:
    return el.indexOf('nonsense') === -1;
  });

console.log(filtered); // ["goodpart", "goodpar2t", "goodpart3"]
```

Or to find, and keep, only those words that begin with `'good'`:

```js
var myarray = ["nonsense", "goodpart", "nonsense2", "goodpar2t", "nonsense3", "goodpart3"],
  filtered = myarray.filter(function(el) {
    // here we test the word ('el') against the regular expression,
    // ^good meaning a string of 'good' that appears at the beginning of the
    // string:
    return (/^good/).test(el);
  });

console.log(filtered); // ["goodpart", "goodpar2t", "goodpart3"]
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).
- [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Comment: *Mmmmm* ... now I understand why the *cough* ... interesting! :)

Comment: Sorry, I just realised I'd not illustrated any other (potentially practical/relevant) approaches. I was presumably updating as you were composing your own answer. Still, that's no reason not to upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a slight variation to @DavidThomas's great answer (+1). This will be helpful in case you decide to exclude array members by value (`nonsense`) instead of by position (`odd`):

```
var myarray = ["nonsense", "goodpart", "nonsense2", "goodpar2t", "nonsense3", "goodpart3"],
    filtered = myarray.filter(function(el) {
        //return only values that do not contain 'nonsense'
        return el.indexOf('nonsense') === -1;
    });
```

```js
var myarray = ["nonsense", "goodpart", "nonsense2", "goodpar2t", "nonsense3", "goodpart3"],
  filtered = myarray.filter(function(el) {
    //return only values that do not contain 'nonsense'
    return el.indexOf('nonsense') === -1;
  });


//output result
$('pre.out').text( JSON.stringify( filtered ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre class="out"></div>
```